# Low speed (bandwidth) for transimitting UDP packets using Boost Asio

Tags: performance, asynchronous, boost, bandwidth, asio

The following is an example of asynchronous UDP client and server I wrote using boost asio to test asio performance (speed). Server is a simple program that echo back the message received from client as follow:

Asynchronous UDP Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;


class udp_server
{
public:
udp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : socket_(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 4000))
{
    start_receive();
}

private:
void start_receive()
{
    socket_.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{

    if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
    {
        std::string copy(recv_buffer_, bytes_transferred);
        boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message( new std::string(recv_buffer_, bytes_transferred) );

        socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(*message), remote_endpoint_,
        boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_send, this, message,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        start_receive();
    }
}

void handle_send(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> /*message*/,
    const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
    std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
{
}

udp::socket socket_;
udp::endpoint remote_endpoint_;
char recv_buffer_[300];
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        udp_server server(io_service);
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The client simply send a message for server in asynchronous mode and wait for the reply and receives the echo backed message from the server. I used chrono to calculate the elapsed time for sending and receiving the message.

The client code is as follow:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
io_service service;
auto ts = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

#define MEM_FN(x)       boost::bind(&self_type::x, shared_from_this())
#define MEM_FN1(x,y)    boost::bind(&self_type::x, shared_from_this(),y)
#define MEM_FN2(x,y,z)  boost::bind(&self_type::x, shared_from_this(),y,z)

class talk_to_svr : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<talk_to_svr>, boost::noncopyable {
    typedef talk_to_svr self_type;
    talk_to_svr(const std::string & message, ip::udp::endpoint ep) 
      : sock_(service), started_(true), message_(message), ep_(ep) {}
    void start(ip::udp::endpoint ep) {
        this->t00 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        sock_.async_connect(ep, MEM_FN1(on_connect,_1));
    }
public:
    typedef boost::system::error_code error_code;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<talk_to_svr> ptr;

    static ptr start(ip::udp::endpoint ep, const std::string & message) {
        ptr new_(new talk_to_svr(message, ep));
        new_->start(ep);
        return new_;
    }
    void stop() {
        if ( !started_) return;
        started_ = false;
        sock_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::shutdown_both);
        sock_.close();
        service.stop();
        std::cout << "Sucket successfully shutdowned and closed" << std::endl;
    }
    bool started() { return started_; }
private:
    void on_connect(const error_code & err) {
    this->t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        if ( !err)      {
            std::cout << "Successfully Connected" << std::endl;
            do_write(message_);

        }
        else            stop();
    }
    void on_read(const error_code & err, size_t bytes) {
        if ( !err) {
        this->t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            std::cout << "Client successfully read " << bytes << " bytes of data as "; //<< std::endl;
            std::string copy(read_buffer_, bytes);
            std::cout << copy << std::endl;
            std::cout.precision(6);
            auto Tc = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(this->t00-ts).count();
            auto Ts = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(this->t0-ts).count();
            auto Te = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(this->t1-ts).count();
            std::cout << "Start to connect @time: " << Tc << " seconds" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Start to send message @time: " << Ts << " second(s)" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Recived messages @time: " << Te << " second(s)" << std::endl;
            auto dt_du = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(this->t1-this->t0).count();
            std::cout << "It tooks " << dt_du << " second(s) to send and recieve " << bytes << " bytes of data" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error occured in reading data from server" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void on_write(const error_code & err, size_t bytes) {
        std::cout << "Client successfully sent " << bytes << " bytes of data" << std::endl;
        do_read();
    }

    void do_read() {

        sock_.async_receive_from(buffer(read_buffer_),
                   ep_,
                   MEM_FN2(on_read,_1,_2));

    }
    void do_write(const std::string & msg) {
        if ( !started() ) return;
        std::copy(msg.begin(), msg.end(), write_buffer_);
        sock_.async_send_to( buffer(write_buffer_, msg.size()), 
                                ep_, MEM_FN2(on_write,_1,_2));
    }

public:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t00;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t0;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t1;

private:
    ip::udp::socket sock_;
    ip::udp::endpoint ep_;
    enum { max_msg = 40 };
    char read_buffer_[max_msg];
    char write_buffer_[max_msg];
    bool started_;
    std::string message_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int port = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::string ipp = std::string(argv[1]);
    std::cout << "Server ip: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Server port: " << (port) << std::endl;
    ip::udp::endpoint ep( ip::address::from_string(ipp), port);
    ts = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    talk_to_svr::start(ep, "Message");

    service.run();
}
```

To compile and execute server:

```
c++ echo_server.cpp -std=c++11 -o echo_client -I /path/to/boost_1_57_0/ -l pthread -l boost_system -l boost_thread

./echo_server
```

To compile and execute client:

```
c++ echo_client.cpp -std=c++11 -o echo_client -I /path/to/boost_1_57_0/ -l pthread -l boost_system -l boost_thread

./echo_client 127.0.0.1 4000
```

While running server and client at same machine (local host), I am wondering why boost asio has such a poor performance as it takes 80 micro second (in average) to send and receive 36 bytes (28 bytes for header + 8 byte for data) which is equivalent to **3.4 Mbits/sec**!!!!

Is there any way to increase UDP socket performance or any other tricks to optimize the code?